# txtデータから読み取った値に新たな列を追加する方法

Tags: python, python3

以下のようなテキストデータがあります。

```
1 10
1 11
1 12
13 1
13 14
```

このtxtデータを読み取って、全ての値が1からなる新たな一列を加えたいです。
つまり、アウトプットは以下のようになります。

```
1 10 1
1 11 1
1 12 1
13 1 1
13 14 1
```

以下のようなコードで単純に`append`をしたのですが、新たな列ではなく、２列目の値に１が追加されてしまいます。
どのように改善すれば良いか教えてください。

```
import numpy as np 

with open(data_path) as f:
    w, h = [int(x) for x in next(f).split()] # w,h=データの形 最初のラインを読み込む
    array = []
    for line in f: # 残りのラインを読み込む
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])

for items in array:
    array.append(1)
    
print(array)
```

Comment: そのプログラムだと、テキストデータの1行目は`w`と`h`に入れられるので、アウトプットの1行目は`1 10 1`ではなく`1 11 1`になるはずですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import numpy as np` とされていますので、[numpy.loadtxt()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy-loadtxt) と [numpy.apply_along_axis()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html#numpy-apply-along-axis) を使ってみます。

```py
import numpy as np

f = np.loadtxt(data_path, dtype=int)
array = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.append(x, [1]), 1, f)
print(array)

[[ 1 10  1]
 [ 1 11  1]
 [ 1 12  1]
 [13  1  1]
 [13 14  1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()])
```

をする際に `1` を追加してしまうと良いでしょう。

```
        array.append([int(x) for x in line.split()].append(1))
```