# テキストファイルを読み込み、複数のデータを配列に格納したい

Tags: python, テキストファイル

Python で以下のようなテキストファイルを読み込みます。
各要素の間には1マス分空白があります。
これを `readline()` で1行ずつ読み込み、各要素を整数型に変えて、例えば1行目なら `[1,0,243,315]` のように1つの配列にする方法はありますでしょうか。

**対象のテキストファイル(例):**

```
1 0 243 315
1 0 241 316
0 7 241 318
0 5 240 322
0 3 241 325
```

**現状のソースコード:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv
import linecache

def main():

    width = 320
    height = 240
    max_value = 42.0
    min_value = 16.5
    num = 0

    face_path = 'd:/study_data/keras-yolo3/result_face.txt'
    nose_path = 'd:/study_data/keras-yolo3/result_nose.txt'

    list_file = open('d:/study_data/get_image/average_temp.txt', 'w')

    os.chdir("d:\\study_data\\get_image\\temperature")

    while True:

        filename = 'temperature_'+format(num)+'.csv'
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            #csvファイルの3行目から読み取る
            csv = pd.read_csv(filename,skiprows=2,header=None)
        else:
            #全て変換したら終了
            print("\nEnd")
            break

        name = '%d ' %num
        list_file.write(name)
        print("\rNo. %d" %num, end='')

        #端の余分な列の除去
        csv = csv.dropna(axis=1)
        #リスト化
        csv = csv.values.tolist()
        #1次元配列化
        csv = np.array(csv)
        #320×240の2次元配列化
        csv = csv.reshape(height,width)
        #print(csv)

        image = np.zeros((height,width),np.uint16)

        #16.5℃を輝度値0, 42.0℃を輝度値255とし、間は0.1℃上昇につき輝度値1上昇
        image = np.clip((csv-min_value)*10, 0, 255)

        #特定の行を読み込む → 最後の改行を削除 → 空白で区切って配列にする
        data_face = linecache.getline(face_path, num+1).replace('\n','')
        data_face = data_face.split(" ")
        data_nose = linecache.getline(nose_path, num+1).replace('\n','')
        data_nose = data_nose.split(" ")

        #現在 data_face,data_noseには読み取ったある列の[num,left,top,right,bottom]が入っている
        if data_face[0] == '' or data_nose[0] == '':
            break

        if data_face[1] == '':
            num += 1

        else:
            if data_nose[1] == '':
                num += 1

            else:
                left = int(data_face[1]) + int(data_nose[1])
                top = int(data_face[2]) + int(data_nose[2])
                right = int(data_face[1]) + int(data_nose[3])
                bottom = int(data_face[2]) + int(data_nose[4])
                temp_sum = 0
                crop_num = 0
                test = cv2.rectangle(image, (left, top), (right, bottom), (255, 0, 0))

                for i in range(top,bottom):
                    for j in range(left,right):
                        temp_sum += csv[i,j]
                        crop_num += 1

                average_temp = float(temp_sum / crop_num)
                list_file.write(str(average_temp))
                num += 1

        cv2.imwrite('d:/study_data/get_image/image_final/image_'+format(num)+'.bmp', image)
        list_file.write('\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: readline ではなく numpy を使っても良いのであれば、[この回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/72653/16894)の様に、[numpy.loadtxt](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy-loadtxt)を使う方法があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます、見てみます!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

文字列を分解するなら [str.split](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split), あとほかに [re.split](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html?highlight=split#re.split) もあります。(後者は SPC, TAB, 復帰・改行 など含めた形で分解できます)

分解した文字列を数値に変換するなら, リストの内包表記, あるいは `int`と`map` で行うことができます

```py
from pathlib import Path
import re
spc = re.compile(r'\s')

fname = Path() / 'testdata.txt'
with fname.open(encoding='utf8') as fp:
    for ln in fp:
        ln = ln.strip()
        if ln:
            arr = ln.split(' ') # あるいは `spc.split(ln)`
            print(list(map(int, arr)))
```